# Custom Button URL redirect not working on Sandbox

Tags: javascript, custom-button

We are working in our sandbox and creating a new custom Button type URL to redirect to a visualforce page I'm getting this error:

[image: SQLException while executing plsql statement]

Here's my button code:

```
window.location = '/apex/FinancialRequest_New'
```

Even I'm setting the button to use it as  URL '/apex/FinancialRequest_New' , the message is the page no longer exist, so still the same issue.